# What is the difference between mutable array & immutable array in ember-data?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I've been running into issues while dealing with ember-data related to immutable arrays like for example "Uncaught Error: The result of a server query is immutable. " This is what I got when i tried to apply `removeObjects()` method on a filtered list of array.

So, I'd like to know the difference & if possible how to convert them to the other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An immutable array just means that it can't be altered directly (as opposed to a mutable array which can be changed).

According to Ember Data documentation, deleting records should be done like this:

> To delete a record, call its deleteRecord() method:
>
> ```
> var person = App.store.find(App.Person, 1); 
> person.deleteRecord();
> ```
>
> The record will not be deleted in the persistence layer until the store's
>   commit() method is called. However, deleted records will immediately
>   be removed from its ModelArray and associations.

Source: https://github.com/emberjs/data#deleting-records

If that's not helpful, could you write a jsfiddle?

Comment: yes this works, thanks :) but when should we use removeObjects() then?

Comment: But I don't think deleteRecord() alters the collection on the client , right?

Comment: deleteRecord() should alter the client. (at least in the sense that all of ember is inherently on the client) Your view's content array is bound the Store, which is what we are altering by using person.deleteRecord(). removeObjects() would only be useful if you had created the array yourself (ie: not from some data-source that needs to be synced whenever something changes in ember)

Comment: Hope I've answered your question. Could you mark that as the answer?

Comment: thanks,I think i missed the binding which is why my view was not being updated...just signed in today(sat n sunday off)